# Chromatic number of a map

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, coloring

[image]

Since in the map each state is connect to another state we are dealing with a complete graph ($K_{12}$). Since, it is a complete graph (every state is connected to every other state), every vertex has the maximal degree of 11. According to Brooks' theorem a graph has a chromatic number equals the  maximum degree, unless it's is a complete graph or an odd cycle, then the chromatic number is maximum degree + 1. Thus the chromatic number is `11 + 1 = 12`

Is this correct?

Comment: Maps are usually planar, so $K_{12}$ couldn't be a map in the usual sense. Also, are you referring to the chromatic index? There's no general easy method for computing the chromatic number, it's generally a hard thing to do (though it's true that the chromatic number of $K_{12}$ is 12).

Comment: My idea was that $K_{12}$ represents the relation "x is adjacent to y" on the map. I'm referring to the chromatic number.

Comment: that simply isn't true. Look at block 1 for example. It's only adjacent to three other blocks. And if you are trying to compute what is usually referred to as the chromatic number, it's 4. I haven't checked all of the blocks, but it's possible that the chromatic index is 12.

Comment: but there are two such blocks labelled '1'.

Comment: You may be right about it being a complete graph then. However, your proof is incorrect, because that theorem only applies to the chromatic index. You have to show that the chromatic number is 12.

Comment: **In graph theory, Brooks' theorem states a relationship between the maximum degree of a graph and its chromatic number.**

Comment: I see. Your proof works then. Just for factual accuracy, the theorem doesn't state that the chromatic number is always at least the maximum degree. The theorem says that the maximum degree is an upper bound, except for the exceptions.

Comment: @MattSamuel, thank you for you feedback. I really appreciate it. You can post your comment as the answer.

Comment: For example, a star graph with a central vertex of any degree you want has chromatic number equal to 2.

Comment: Yes, it must be smaller or equal to. That was a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked, but provided that the graph is complete your proof is correct. Brooks theorem gives an upper bound on the chromatic number for all graphs, that being the maximum degree, except for complete graphs and odd cycles, where it states the chromatic number is equal to the maximum degree plus one. For an example showing that we don't have equality in general, consider a star graph with at least four vertices. The maximum degree is at least 3, but the chromatic number is 2.